Delimit max width of write_html() function FPDF2
How to set max width of a write_html()? I have a string with html tags and i need print the text formatted inside of a rectangle background. But the texts leak to the edge of the page.
How can i delimit the maximum width of the formatted text?
The problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found a workaround. The page margins (set_margin_left()) can limit the HTML text.
More information here.

I edited your answer a bit for clarity. It would be even more helpful if you share an actual code sample of how you solved it.
